# writing a validator for hashtag fields in model of django

Tags: python, regex, django, validation

I have a model that has some of fields:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=160, help_text='H1(SEO)',blank=True)
    hashtags = models.TextField(blank=True, validators=[validate_hashtags])
```

the hashtag inputs should be like:

```
#sth #sth #sth
```

in fact I need to have a space after each hashtag except the last one(the last hashtag doesn't need any space after it). here is my validator function using regex

```
def validate_hashtags(value):
    string1 = value.split()
    string2 = re.findall("(#\\w+ )", value)
    if re.match("^#\\w+$", string1[-1]):
        matching_counter = len(string2) + 1
    else:
        matching_counter = len(string2)
    if len(string1) != matching_counter:
        raise ValidationError("please enter # in the correct format")
```

but it doesn't work properly, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regex to validate the input. Splitting won't be needed in this case.

`^(#\w+\s+)+$`

```
#sth #sth #sth - Valid
#sth sth #sth - Invalid
#sth#sth #sth  - Invalid
```

Hope it solves the problem.

Comment: @m.ar You have switches the accepted answer, but note that [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/N2uFQr/1) does not match `#sth #sth #sth` if it is the only text on that line. Is only matches if there are 1+ whitespace chars following and `\s` will also match a newline so it could match all empty following newlines as well. The quantifier also repeats the capturing group which is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no space after the last hashtag, you could use match a hashtag followed by 1+ word chars and then repeat a group which matches a space and 1+ word chars.

```
^#\w+(?: #\w+)*$
```

Explanation

- `^` Assert start of string
- `#\w+` Match `#`, then 1+ word chars
- `(?: #\w+)*` Non capturing group, repeat 0+ times a space, `#` and 1+ word chars
- `$` Assert end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9D7KTj/1)

If there can be 1+ spaces or tabs after the pattern you could repeat a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[ \t]+`:

```
^#\w+(?:[ \t]+#\w+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9D7KTj/2)